# IDictionary AddAndReturn extension for fluent interface

Tags: c#, dictionary, fluent-interface, idictionary

What's nice about [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), which is a great JavaScript library, is to be able to get the element you are working on as return value. Here is an example of what I am referring to:

```js
$(function() { 
    $("#poo").css("clear", "both").css("margin", "10px");
});
```

I would like to implement the same for the C# `IDictionary` `interface` so that I can write code as follows:

```cs
IDictionary<string, string> myDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>().
        Add("key1", "value1").
        Add("key2", "value2").
        Add("key3", "value3");
```

So I have created an extension method as below for `IDictionary`:

```cs
public static IDictionary<string, string> AddAndReturn(this IDictionary<string, string> dictionary, string key, string value) {
    dictionary.Add(key, value);
    return dictionary;
}
```

And now I am able to use it like:

```cs
IDictionary<string, string> poo = 
    new Dictionary<string,string>().
        AddAndReturn("key1", "value1").
        AddAndReturn("key2", "value2").
        AddAndReturn("key3", "value3");
```

I wonder if I am following the right path here.

Is what I am doing a poor man's fluent interface implementation or totally unrelated to that?

Is there any known case for this implementation in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While your implementation pattern is correct (and a common one at that,) your use case is probably not the best choice. <s>Object</s> Collection initializers work for dictionary types too:

```
var poo =  new Dictionary<string,string> {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", "value2" },
        { "key3", "value3" }, // this is permissible
};
```

The compiler magically turns this into Add(string, string) calls. Btw, the apparently erroneous comma after the last pair is deliberate. The compiler allows this so you can simplify logic in code generators such as T4.

Comment: Quick bit of terminology: these are *collection initializers*. But yes, this is the idiomatic approach.

Comment: Since C# I-don't-remember-which-version, you can use a special syntax `new Dictionary<string, string> { ["key"] = "value" }`

Comment: In fact, collection initializers are available for every type that has a (possibly extension) method named `Add()`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any known case for this implementation in C#?

Regarding this, I would like to add that the `StringBuilder.Append()` method returns the `StringBuilder`, making the method chainable, such as:

```cs
sb.Append("a").Append("b"). Append("c")
```

But there aren't many other examples like that in .NET.